# Javascript "Access is Denied" error when trying to use jquery plugin with jQuery 1.7.1

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins

A jquery plugin named "binaryajax.js" exists that can be used to read and examine data from images.  When I try to include this script in my page (just including it, without even using it), I get a javascript "Access is Denied" error in jQuery 1.7.1. No other jquery plugin I have ever used has had an error like this. I have seen no other reference to anyone else having this error except for me.  I would like to be able to use this because I need to examine the EXIF orientation tag inside of an image file in javascript, but this error is preventing me from doing so.  Can someone explain why I would be getting this and what I can do to make it work for me?  Here is the reference to binaryajax.js:

http://www.nihilogic.dk/labs/binaryajax/binaryajax.js

All I am doing to get the error is to include the following in my page:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/binaryajax.js"></script>
```

What am I doing wrong, if anything?

EDIT:

Through much trial and error, I tracked down what is causing the error, although I still do not know how to correct it:

On my home page I have two links of the following format:

```
<a onclick="$('#home-form-settings').submit();">
```

Each one has click-event handlers that point to a form on the home page and will cause a submit of the form.

These links are not even on the page where I am including and trying to use binaryajax.js, but because they are on the home page they for some reason get included in every other page I visit in my asp.net MVC web application.  If I remove these links, I do not get the Access Denied error but their presence is preventing me from using this plugin.  Does that make sense?

How can I use the plugin on some other page and keep these links on the home page?

Comment: Are your images hosted on the same domain as the script?

Comment: What does jquery have to do with this? i don't see where that plugin uses jquery, or any other library for that matter.

Comment: @PaulS.: I believe so but let me verify that.  There is just one image so I will test what happens if I do not even use an image. If the error no longer happens then the image is the issue otherwise it is independent of the image.

Comment: @KevinB:  What this has to do with jquery is that the error is happening inside of jQuery 1.7.1 if I include that script in my page.

Comment: So if you remove jquery, the error doesn't happen? Then, what does binaryajax have to do with this? does the error only happen when they are both included, not either or?

Comment: @KevinB: I have not tried that but I can test it.  However, I need jquery to be active at the same time I use this plugin.  It is of no value to me to have this plugin but to not have jquery.

Comment: This is likely a bug within jquery's support area if it's happening without you using jquery at all. I'd suggest trying to upgrade to a newer version.

Comment: I understand that, but debugging involves figuring out what is causing the error and eliminating those things that aren't causing the error. If we can confirm that the error is just in jquery and not related to the combination of jquery and the plugin, then we can just look at jquery and ignore the plugin.

Comment: @PaulS: As a test I removed all of my custom script from the page and also all images from the page, and the Access Denied error still happens.  So the error is not caused by an image hosted on a foreign domain.  Instead it seems to be an incompatibility between this plugin and jquery 1.7.1.

Comment: Cannot reproduce your error http://jsfiddle.net/JVhTz/ .

Comment: I found some additional information about the issue.  See my EDIT above.